# Android O: AccessibilityService

Tags: android, accessibilityservice

I try to use the AccessibilityService with Android O but it does not create this Service.

Manifest:

```
<service
        android:name=".AccessService"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.accessibilityservice"
            android:resource="@xml/accessibility_service_config" />
    </service>
```

XML Configuration:

```
<accessibility-service xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                   android:description="@string/app_name"
                   android:accessibilityEventTypes="typeAllMask"
                   android:accessibilityFlags="flagRequestFilterKeyEvents|flagIncludeNotImportantViews"
                   android:accessibilityFeedbackType="feedbackAllMask"
                   android:notificationTimeout="100"
                   android:canRetrieveWindowContent="true"
                   android:canRequestFilterKeyEvents="true"
                   android:settingsActivity="com.example.test.MainActivity"
/>
```

I added Log Output for all Methods of my extended AccessibilityService Class, but also the onCreate was never called. I can activate the Service in the Android Settings and i bind it to the both volume buttons and if i press both together he always say that this is now activated. It does not say disabled or something like this. The Android Settings Page says its active.

My AccessibilityService Class has only Log output. I didn't do anything else in this class.

Do i missed something? Is there anything else in Android O what i have to do?
I tried it based on this tutorial: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/accessibility/services.html

I want to catch long press volume button.

Answer (score 3):

It's unclear what you mean when you say that it doesn't create the service, since you also say that the Android Settings page recognises it as active.

I tried creating an accessibility service to run it on Android O and it seems to work.

Here is my service which, as you say your service behaves, just logs:

```
public class LoggingA11yService extends AccessibilityService {

    @Override
    public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) {
        Log.d("!!!", "onAccessibilityEvent: " + event);
    }

    @Override
    public void onInterrupt() {
        Log.d("!!!", "onInterrupt");
    }

}
```

It's necessary to declare this service in the manifest, and provide a configuration for it in XML (some properties are configurable programmatically, but all are configurable via XML so this is the preferred approach):

```
<application>

    <service android:name=".LoggingA11yService"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE"
        android:label="@string/accessibility_service_label">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.accessibilityservice"
            android:resource="@xml/accessibilityservice" />
    </service>

    <activity ...

</application>
```

`@xml/accessibilityservice`:

```
<accessibility-service xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:accessibilityEventTypes="typeAllMask"
    android:accessibilityFeedbackType="feedbackSpoken"
    android:accessibilityFlags="flagDefault"
    android:canRetrieveWindowContent="true"
    android:description="@string/accessibility_service_description"
    android:notificationTimeout="100" />
```

Then simply enabling the service by navigating to Settings > Accessibility > LoggingA11yService > toggle on, should activate it.

I can see in logcat the output as I use my device e.g.:

```
05-21 10:34:25.848 15998-15998/com.novoda.androidskeleton D/!!!:
onAccessibilityEvent: EventType: TYPE_WINDOW_STATE_CHANGED;
EventTime: 113655863; PackageName: com.android.settings;
MovementGranularity: 0; Action: 0 [ ClassName: com.android.settings.SubSettings;
Text: [Label Logging A11y Service]; ContentDescription: null;
ItemCount: -1; CurrentItemIndex: -1; IsEnabled: true;
IsPassword: false; IsChecked: false; IsFullScreen: true;
Scrollable: false; BeforeText: null; FromIndex: -1; ToIndex: -1;
ScrollX: -1; ScrollY: -1; MaxScrollX: -1; MaxScrollY: -1;
AddedCount: -1; RemovedCount: -1; ParcelableData: null ];
recordCount: 0
```

Note the docs say that if there are multiple services that can handle the same event, then they will only send the event to all services if the services provide different types of feedback. Otherwise, the first service that registered will get the event - check if this is not your case by disabling any other accessibility service while testing yours.